# Symfony - FormType in a ManyToMany (with extra data) relation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 6.
I have two entities : Student and Trombinoscope
A Trombinoscope can have many Students, and a Student can be in many Trombinoscopes.
It's a ManyToMany relation, but i want some extra data; so i need to create a third entity "StudentTrombinoscope"

```
class Student
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TrombinoscopeStudent::class, mappedBy="Student")
     */
    private $trombinoscopeStudents;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->trombinoscopeStudents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setName(?string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, TrombinoscopeStudent>
     */
    public function getTrombinoscopeStudents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->trombinoscopeStudents;
    }

    public function addTrombinoscopeStudent(TrombinoscopeStudent $trombinoscopeStudent): self
    {
        if (!$this->trombinoscopeStudents->contains($trombinoscopeStudent)) {
            $this->trombinoscopeStudents[] = $trombinoscopeStudent;
            $trombinoscopeStudent->setStudent($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTrombinoscopeStudent(TrombinoscopeStudent $trombinoscopeStudent): self
    {
        if ($this->trombinoscopeStudents->removeElement($trombinoscopeStudent)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($trombinoscopeStudent->getStudent() === $this) {
                $trombinoscopeStudent->setStudent(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
class Trombinoscope
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $label;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TrombinoscopeStudent::class, mappedBy="trombinoscope")
     */
    private $trombinoscopeStudents;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->trombinoscopeStudents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLabel(): ?string
    {
        return $this->label;
    }

    public function setLabel(string $label): self
    {
        $this->label = $label;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, TrombinoscopeStudent>
     */
    public function getTrombinoscopeStudents(): Collection
    {
        return $this->trombinoscopeStudents;
    }

    public function addTrombinoscopeStudent(TrombinoscopeStudent $trombinoscopeStudent): self
    {
        if (!$this->trombinoscopeStudents->contains($trombinoscopeStudent)) {
            $this->trombinoscopeStudents[] = $trombinoscopeStudent;
            $trombinoscopeStudent->setTrombinoscope($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTrombinoscopeStudent(TrombinoscopeStudent $trombinoscopeStudent): self
    {
        if ($this->trombinoscopeStudents->removeElement($trombinoscopeStudent)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($trombinoscopeStudent->getTrombinoscope() === $this) {
                $trombinoscopeStudent->setTrombinoscope(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

```
class TrombinoscopeStudent
{
    use BlameableTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Trombinoscope::class, inversedBy="trombinoscopeStudents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $trombinoscope;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Student::class, inversedBy="trombinoscopeStudents")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $student;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json", nullable=true)
     */
    private $otherData = [];

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTrombinoscope(): ?Trombinoscope
    {
        return $this->trombinoscope;
    }

    public function setTrombinoscope(?Trombinoscope $trombinoscope): self
    {
        $this->trombinoscope = $trombinoscope;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStudent(): ?Student
    {
        return $this->Student;
    }

    public function setStudent(?Student $student): self
    {
        $this->student = $student;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOtherData(): ?array
    {
        return $this->otherData;
    }

    public function setOtherData(?array $otherData): self
    {
        $this->otherData = $otherData;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I have an interface to add students to a new trombinoscope (or edit students in a trombinoscope, a typical CRUD).
I want to have all students in a select list

I don't succeed to create a FormType to generate this select list
Here are my attempts :

```
->add('trombinoscopeStudents', null, [
    'multiple' => true,
    'choice_label' => function ($choice) {
        return $choice->getStudent()->getName();
    }
])
```

Fail - Return only data in "TrombinoscopeStudent" table, not all data in "Student" table

New attempt with a Collection

```
->add('trombinoscopeStudents', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => TrombinoscopeStudentType::class,
    'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true
])
```

my subForm TrombinoscopeStudentType

```
class TrombinoscopeStudentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('student', EntityType::class, [
                'multiple' => true,
                'class' => Student::class,
                'choice_label' => function ($choice) {
                    return $choice->getName();
                },
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TrombinoscopeStudent::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Fail - Return a list of form, not a select list with all students

I don't want a "unmapped" field, i think Symfony/Doctrine can be easily handle this case...
Could you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: Show your `TrombinoscopeStudentType::class`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to add an existing students in a new trombinoscope, just create a TrombinoscopeStudentType form with an entityType::class for the students.
I don't think you can use an entityType::class and a collectiontype of the same Entity on the same form because it is redundant.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).